# JavaScript UI controls for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've been working with Django and Kendo UI, and jQuery to make web pages. Up until now, I like a lot the UI that can be used with these.

I check in the Kendo UI web that support for ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC is only a trial, so I was wondering if there something like KendoUI and jQuery UI for ASP.NET. I'm a beginner on this, so i don't know much.

Can you please help me?

Comment: are you looking for a framework that 'renders' the jQuery/Kendo components right in front of you, in the ASP NET framework? or are you wondering how to use jQuery along with .NET?

Comment: Nope, I'm wondering how if there's a resource that tells you how to use Kendo UI with ASP.NET without the support that the ASP.NET 4 MVC version gives you.

Answer (score 0):

The open source version of [KendoUI Web](http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx) can be used with any platform (php, asp.net, java, etc).  It's just javascript ui library.  The asp.net mvc wrapper that comes with the full product just wraps the javascript calls with mvc html helpers... no reason you can't do that yourself.